# Why is my accordion not displaying as such?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm referencing recent jQuery and jQuery-UI css and js files:

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

and have this html:

```
<div id="accordion">
     <h3><a href="#">First item</a></h3>
    <div>CONTENT FOR FIRST ITEM</div>
     <h3><a href="#">Second item</a></h3>
    <div>CONTENT FOR SECOND ITEM</div>
     <h3><a href="#">Third item</a></h3>
    <div>CONTENT FOR THIRD ITEM</div>
     <h3><a href="#">Fourth item</a></h3>
    <div>CONTENT FOR FOURTH ITEM</div>
</div>
```

...and this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        event: "mouseover",
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

...which runs fine in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/BhWEE/) when configured for jQuery 1.9.1, Migrate 1.1.0, and jQuery UI 1.9.2

So I'm using newer versions of the last two than what are available in jsFiddle, but that wouldn't be a problem, would it?

On my page it looks like this:

[image]

IOW, not very accordion-like.

What's the problem?

### UPDATE

Just to be sure that the *newer* version of jQuery-UI was not the problem, I reverted from 1.10.3 to 1.9.2 (the version that works in jsFiddle), and it still fails. So, I went back to the new AND I added another stylesheet from the jQueryUI site, namely:

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

No diff, though; fiddlesticks!

Comment: yea.. u need to use updated plugin and appropriate plugins for accordion

Comment: Looks like perhaps your jquery.ui.all might not find the files neeeded. Please look in the chrome console or Firefox with firebug to see you have `@import "jquery.ui.base.css";`
`@import "jquery.ui.theme.css";` in the right place

Comment: @mplungjan: The versions are shown at the beginning of my question. I think I'm using the latest version of jquery-ui (1.10.3), so I don't see a problem with my versions. As mentioned, my other versions (for jQuery proper, migrate, and modernizr) are all up-to-date, too...

Comment: @Praveen: I need a separate accordion plugin, additional to jQuery UI?

Comment: @mplungjan: Your jsfiddle doesn't show the accordion until the jQuery UI 1.9.2 [che,ti]ckbox is [che,ti]cked. This leads me to infer that it should work as long as I'm referencing jQuery 1.9.2 or better - which I am...

Comment: Sorry what exactly is your question? Is it functionality or style?

Comment: @Dom: I guess you could say both - the accordion "look" is nowhere to be seen, as the image shows. Compare that with the jsfiddle, and you'll see that the jsfiddle does show the accordion, whereas in VS it doesn't.

Comment: @mplungjan - it's stylish enough; I'm not trying to create something Louvre- or Prado-worthy here; I just want the accordion functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather embarrassing, but it was a rookie mistake on my part: I forgot to encase the jQuery in a script block! I reckon I've got to train myself to be more (or less?) of a blockhead.

I should have grokked something was awry or amiss when my jQuery wouldn't color up or let itself be formatted/tidied up in VS.

The coin finally dropped when I saw my jQuery written out at the bottom of the page.

Now that the code is this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            event: "mouseover",
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

...it works fine.